# Promise made under the influence of religious ocd

Tags: waswasa

Assalamualaikum.
May Allah reward you for helping me out ASAP.
Ughmm i have been under the influence of ocd since 5 years mainly religious OCD.
Once i made a promise to Allah that if a picture Doesn't get sent to my cousin's (cause i looked horrible in that picture)(it may be sent by my relatives to any family group thats why)
, i will never send any picture in future to them.
I didn't utter anything i just made that intention in my mind but i am sure I did all this cause of my OCD cause a normal person would never make such conditions and promises.
IS THIS PROMISE VALID???
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem since you didn't say anything out loud. I'm pretty sure Allah doesn't judge you on what you think, but he judges you on what you do and what you say.

Your OCD makes it harder for you (and you regret making that intention?). So I guess it doesn't really count and you can just forget about your intention and **I don't think it's valid**, since you didn't say it out loud and you weren't 100% conscious (because of your OCD).